# Adding 1 string to end of file, Even when ran multiple times to change MD5

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I need to change the md5 of my files, Sometimes once, sometimes multiple times. A friend gave me this script to add a string to the end of the file but i think i may be adding it multiple times when i had a look in a hex editor i saw it twice. I'm also not sure if this is actually editing anything else. Just wanted to get it checked out before i started using it.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "md5change`date +%s`"
cat $1 | sed --in-place '/md5change/s/.*//' $1
sed -i '/^[ \t]*$/d' $1
echo "md5change`date +%s`" >> $1
echo "done"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script seems to presume that there's a line (or more lines) in the file containing the string "md5change". It's displaying such a string on the screen, emptying (but not removing) the line containing that string, then removing all empty lines in the file, finally appending a new "md5change" line to the file (which is not necessarily the same as the displayed one in the first `echo`), finally printing "done". You have to remove the `cat $1 |` part, though, because `$1` is already presented as an "inplace" argument to `sed`.

Edit: I presume you can compactify your code, e.g.:

```
timestamp=md5change$(date +%s)
echo "${timestamp}"
sed -i "/md5change/s/.*/${timestamp}/" "$1"
echo "done"
```

(Note: This code is not equivalent to your code template, since your code deletes all empty lines in the file, removes multiple "md5change" entries in the file, and appends on the end of the file. Where this compact version changes existing "md5change" entries by the new one. My guess is that it's what you actually want, and it fixes some issues with your original code.)

Comment: It doesen't seem to be working. I run it and it has the same MD5. `root@sd-71801:/var/www/html# md5sum original.3ds
9dc55e0dcdd99605035872211c6c1327  original.3d 
root@sd-71801:/var/www/html# md5change original.3ds
md5change1427284041
done
root@sd-71801:/var/www/html# md5sum original.3ds
9dc55e0dcdd99605035872211c6c1327  original.3ds`

Comment: Exoon, the comment contains only trash; it doesn't explain anything. I explained what the original script seems to have been intended to do. Did the original script that you have posted do anything to change the md5sum? It would help if you'd show the actual data that shall be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!  Here is a one-liner solution using your chosen tools, `sed` and `date`:

```
$ sed -i "s/^md5change.*/md5change$(date +%s)/" FILE
```

I'm not sure why you wanted that second `sed` command (which removes all lines lacking non-space characters, though non-GNU `sed` may not recognize `\t`).  Assuming GNU, add `; /^[ \t]$/d` to the end of the quoted portion.  Without GNU, merely put a literal tab in place of the escaped version.

The one-liner won't work if you don't already have an "md5change" line.  For that, you'd need another line first:

```
#!/bin/sh
epoch=$(date +%s)
if grep ^md5change "$1"
  then sed -i "s/^md5change.*/md5change$epoch/" "$1"
  else echo "md5change$epoch" >> "$1"
fi
```

**Note that `date +%s` is *not* portable!**  The POSIX standard does not specify it, though both GNU and BSD versions of `date` support it.  You can either use `perl -e "print time"` or do all of the logic in a real language (like `perl`):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i -pn
$_ = $1 . time . "\n" if /^(md5change)/
```

This looks for a line beginning with "md5change" and then replaces it with the matched part (`$1` is "md5change") concatenated with the epoch and then a newline.  `-i` will overwrite the input(s) (just like `sed -i` – which is the same as `sed --in-place`), `-n` iterates through each line of the input with the default variable (`$_`) representing the current line, and `-p` prints `$_` at the end of the `-e` commands (per line).

To remove blank lines, convert perl's `-pn` argument into `-n` and add a new line at the end that says `print if /\S/`

You can convert that script to a one liner for the command line as well:

```
$ perl -i -pne '$_ = $1 . time . "\n" if /^(md5change)/'
```

or

```
$ perl -i -ne '$_ = $1 . time . "\n" if /^(md5change)/; print if /\S/'
```

To deal with the input file missing the "md5change" line:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i
my $md5change = 0;
while (<>) {
  if (/^(md5change)/) {
    $_ = $1 . time . "\n";
    $md5change = 1;
  }
  print;
} continue {
  if (eof and not $md5change) {
    $md5change = 0;
    print "md5change" . time . "\n";
  }
}
```